# WPF comparing strings in separate files

Tags: c#, wpf

I have 2 files one is a CSV file and the second is a text file. My requirement is I want to check if the strings contained in the CSV file exist in the text file. After I have performed this check I want to add those CSV strings that exist in the text file to an IEnnumerable collection which I will use for binding. E.g if CSV conatins "aa", "bb", "cc" and text file contains "bb", "ee", "ff", "cc", "bb" my collection should contain "bb", "cc", "bb". I have made a start on reading from a CSV file using the code below. Can anyone provide a solution pls? Thanks - Ben

```
public class VM
{
    public VM()
    {
        Words = LoadWords(filePath);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Words { get; private set; }

    string filePath = @"Z:\My Documents\Words.csv";

    private static IEnumerable<string> LoadWords(String filePath)
    {

        List<String> words = new List<String>();

        try
        {
            foreach (String line in File.ReadAllLines(filePath))
            {
                string[] rows = line.Split(',');

                words.AddRange(rows);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

            return words;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should rephrase your question. It has nothing do with WPF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with LINQ, something like:

```
var csv = new[] { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
var text = new[] { "bb", "ee", "ff", "cc", "bb" };

IEnumerable<string> collectionToBind = text.Where(t => csv.Contains(t));
```